# Load multiple Bitmaps with the same Function

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, loader

i got a basic problem with loading a Bitmap from a URLRequest.
The problem is, that loading a Bitmap is to much code to write it every time I want to load an Image. So i thought about some function:

```
var bitmap1:Bitmap = bitmapForURL("test1.gif");
var bitmap2:Bitmap = bitmapForURL("test2.gif");
function bitmapForURL(url:String):Bitmap
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.x = size * numChildren;
    loader.load(request);
    return Bitmap(loader);
}
```

Unfortunately at the end of the function the Bitmap isn't created already. -> DOESN'T WORK
Then I read about the Event.Complete-Listener, but in that case i loose the reference back to my bitmap1 and bitmap2.

```
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ioCompleteHandler);
```

My question is: How can i implement a imageLoader-function, that gives me back a Bitmap?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Loader is an asynchronous function.  You will need a complete event handler for when data has been loaded.

Comment: In short no, but there are some alternatives. You could simply return a `Loader` object instead, however even if you add it to the stage, the image being loaded may not have loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class BitmapLoader
{
    private var m_loaders:Dictionary = new Dictionary( true );

    public function loadImage( url:String, callback:Function ):void
    {
        // create our request and loader
        var request:URLRequest  = new URLRequest( url );
        var loader:Loader       = new Loader;
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this._onComplete );

        // add the callback to our dictionary
        this.m_loaders[loader] = callback;

        // load it
        loader.load( request );
    }

    private function _onComplete( e:Event ):void
    {
        // get our loader
        var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo   = ( e.target as LoaderInfo );
        var loader:Loader           = loaderInfo.loader;

        // remove the event listener
        loaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this._onComplete );

        // call our function
        if( loader in this.m_loaders )
        {
            // call our callback
            this.m_loaders[loader]( loaderInfo.content as Bitmap );

            // remove the loader from the dictionary
            this.m_loaders[loader] = null;
            delete this.m_loaders[loader];
        }
        else
            trace( "We don't have a callback for the loader" );
    }
}
```

As already mentioned, `Loader.load()` is asynchronous, so you'll have to work with callbacks (or Events, or Signals). This is a simple class that stores the loaders as a key in a Dictionary, with the value as the callback we want to call.

You can further extend it so that it copes with multiple loads to the same bitmap (either returning the loaded Bitmap, or having multiple listeners to one load) etc etc